# File is in use by another process but canRead() returns true

Tags: java, filenotfoundexception

I'm using another program to convert bin files to xml and then I'm trying to read the file.
With the following code:

```
File file = new File(currentPath + "/ammunition.bin");
File file2 = fileTools.convert(file);
ArrayList<String> asd = fileTools.readFile(file2);
```

I get FileNotFoundException, "file is in use by another process".
What makes this weird is that file.canRead() returns true even though i get the exception.
Here is the rest of the code:

```
public ArrayList<String> readFile(File file) {

    ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
    Scanner reader;
    try {
        reader = new Scanner(file, "UTF-8");
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        boolean b = file.canRead();
        StringWriter errors = new StringWriter();
        ex.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(errors));
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, errors.toString());
        alertError("readFile\n" + b + " " + ex.getMessage());
        return null;
    }
    while (reader.hasNext()) {
        result.add(reader.nextLine());
    }
    reader.close();
    return result;
}

public File changeFileExtension(File f, String ext) {
    String name = f.getAbsolutePath();
    int i = name.lastIndexOf(".");
    name = name.substring(0, i) + "." + ext;
    f = new File(name);
    return f;
}


public File convert(File file) {

    File binConverter = new File(this.currentPath + "\\GibbedsTools\\Gibbed.Avalanche.BinConvert.exe");

    if (!binConverter.exists()) {
        alertError("convert\nGibbedsTools is missing, it should be in\n" + this.currentPath + "\\GibbedsTools\\Gibbed.Avalanche.BinConvert.exe");
        return null;
    }

    if (!file.exists()) {
        alertError("convert\nFile does not exist\n" + file.getAbsolutePath());
    }

    String name = file.getName();
    String extension = name.substring(name.lastIndexOf(".") + 1, name.length());

    Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();

    try {
        rt.exec("cmd.exe /c " + "\"\"" + this.currentPath + "\\GibbedsTools\\Gibbed.Avalanche.BinConvert.exe\" \"" + file.getAbsolutePath() + "\"\"");
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        alertError("binToXml\n" + ex.getMessage());
        return null;
    }

    File file2 = changeFileExtension(file, extension.equals("xml") ? "bin" : "xml");

    int timepassed = 0;

    while (!file2.exists() || !file2.canWrite() || timepassed <= 50) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(50);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            alertError("binToXml\n" + ex.getMessage());
            return null;
        }
        timepassed += 50;
        if (timepassed > 3000) {
            if (!file2.exists()) {
                alertError("convert\nError, binconverter probably crashed (No xml file created after 3 seconds from passing file to binconverter)\n"
                        + "xml file should be in:\n"
                        + file2.getAbsolutePath() + "     Found: " + file2.exists());
                return null;
            }
        }
        if (timepassed > 6000 && !file2.canWrite()) {
            alertError("convert\nCan't write to the xml file after 6 seconds from passing the file to binconverter."
                    + file2.getAbsolutePath() + "     Can write: " + file2.canWrite());
            return null;
        }
    }

    return file2;
}
```

Comment: exactly at what point do you get the exception?

Comment: At "reader = new Scanner(file, "UTF-8");"

Comment: try this: instead of sending the file as parameter , just create it in ur method and see if you get the same problem. if you don't get same problem then you are doing something wrong before calling the method

Comment: Create it in what point? In convert method?

Comment: yeah, before initializing the scanner

Comment: Same error when I made the file at the start of convert method.

Comment: Ahh I see what happens. you are running an external program. you must close that before trying to access the file again. try this: ***rt.exit(0);*** before ***return file2;***

Comment: rt.exit(0); shuts down my own program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of having :

```
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
.
.
.
```

try this instead:

```
 Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe /c " + "\"\"" + this.currentPath + "\\GibbedsTools\\Gibbed.Avalanche.BinConvert.exe\" \"" + file.getAbsolutePath() + "\"\"");
```

then you can wait for it to finish by using:

```
p.waitFor();
```

once external program finishes it then releases the file.
better solution would be using [Processbuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.htmlhttp://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html)

You can also destroy the process by using

```
p.destroy();
```

of course try to avoid using it. unless program is pain to deal with.